# Two images next to each other in html, bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm a newbie working on HTML, I have two images of different sizes and I am trying to put them side by side on the same row, using html and bootstrap.

Here is my current code:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img src="https://x1" alt="logo"
         id="logo"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img src="https://x2" alt="ex" id="img2">
    </div>
   </div>
```

They show up side by side, but with differents sizes, how should I resize them so that they fit as two square images one next to the other. Here is my css affecting the images:

```
img{
      margin-top:25px;
      width:100%;
    }
```

Any help greatly apreciated!

Comment: Is the size of the images the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to have them the same height. So if they have the same width/height ration, they'll also have the same width, if not, they at least have the same height in the row. (If they would have the same height *and* width, but a different height/width ration, one or both would be distorted!). Use this CSS for that:

```
img {
  height:100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Note: The parent element needs to have a height definition for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css. You basically need to set the width to `100%` which you have already done and then give them a fixed `height` so they are both the same size. Check the fiddle below.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/su16pzqc/

```
img{
      margin-top:25px;
      width:100%;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you did, however, in your example and this happened to me too, the images look distorted. Does this mean that it's an image problem? i.e. Should my images already be the same size and quality?

Comment: @arziankorpen yes, its a matter of resolution.

Answer (score -1):

I made this JSFiddle example with your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/onjaL3bu/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="logo" id="logo"> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" alt="ex" id="img2">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img{

}
```

You dont need to use any CSS to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Also, you should take a look at the classes that I used.  You were using way too many classes.

Comment: OP wants the images to be same size in square shape.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however as sparta93 commented, in your example the images are not the same size side by side. I also had my images looking like the ones in your example.

Comment: @arziankorpen, just use CSS `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` along with a fixed height on the image elements (you can obviously use CSS for that too) and you will be done.